# Sync Square POS sales with Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, square

I currently have a Woocommerce online store and Square POS system. Everything syncs perfectly fine except my sales. Any sales taken through the POS i.e cash and card in the shop is not showing up in woocommerce and vice versa, web payments are not showing in the Square app.

Is there a way that this can be achieved? I am more interested in the POS sales showing up in my wordpress/woocommerce online store than the other way round.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please give a little detail as to the context of what you are doing, what you are seeing and finally what you expected to see. That'll make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I have a wordpress website with woocommerce. I have the following plugin: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-square/?utm_source=square%20app%20marketplace&utm_medium=partners&utm_campaign=partner%20promotions

Comment: The problem I have is this plugin only syncs my inventory and product details but not the sales and I would like the sales to sync between the two systems

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am looking for similar myself. I thought the plugin did that but to me it looks like it does not which seems pointless.

Comment: Unfortunately not. the plugin syncs my inventory in woocommerce and sends all my sales to quickbooks as well as when someone purchases online using Square it shows up in my square sales but my sales in my shop does not appear in woocommerce which is frustrating as it does everything else. I hope this makes sense.